# Saving a video's frames as still images in Java

Tags: java, video, streaming, video-streaming

I want to convert a video, say **catch.avi**, into its frames (as images) in Java so that I can make a Map view of my house. I suppose I'll get about a hundred frames, which I'll want to put into an `ArrayList`. That way, I can traverse the list to generate my Map Look.

The thing that's giving me trouble is converting the video file into its constituent frames. I've studied the Java Media Framework, but haven't got any idea how to do this. Please guide me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, your question as written doesn't really fit this site. Please see [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). In short, we don't really do broad "please guide me" questions here. If you can be more specific, possibly with a code sample, we'd love to help you!

Comment: @LordTorgamus Yes a code sample will help me surely..I just want a push.I will do the rest

Comment: You've misunderstood me; _you_ need to give _us_ a code sample, or else we can't know where you're stuck.

Comment: @LordTorgamus I am completely new with java media framework.i have expertise in java but I haven't used JMF.

Comment: I think this will show you how to do it: http://www.koders.com/java/fid982E0FAD3EBBD25C34422F40F12CB323E36A0779.aspx?s=215

Comment: I'd start with Processing for this sort of thing- http://processing.org/reference/libraries/#computer_vision or OPENCV http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/ . I think JMF is depreciated.

Comment: @Andrew It looks informative Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMF is not obslete.here are some tutorials that will definitely hep u.[enter link description here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jmf/)